# Using servername as a parameter for Go To URL in SSRS

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting-services

In Visual Studio 2010 I have a pie chart which, on clicking the chart, uses the action Go To URL to bring up a report.

Where the servername is hard coded, this means I bring up the same report regardless of which environment I am in (i.e. when on Test server, the link is still to the Live report).

I'd like to use a parameter but, despite extensive Googling, I'm getting nowhere.

For example, I've amended the Go to URL so it starts like this: 
    ="javascript:void(window.open('http://"& Parameters!MyServerName.Value &".

I added a report paramter @MyServerName where available values = none and default values = 
    =mid(Globals!ReportServerUrl,8,instr(globals!ReportServerUrl,"/")-8)

However, in Preview I get error "The DefaultValue expression for the reprt parameter 'ServerName' contains an error: Argument 'Length' must be greater or equal to zero."

If anyone can correct this or *provide a better way* I'd be most grateful!

I also tried using =@@servername as the default value but got error "[BC30201] Expression expected."

I could also use Go To Report, but it doesn't give me the control that javascript does.

Comment: please share an example of the url and what part you need as the parameter default value.

Comment: Hi, the actual URL is not important. The bit I want to parameterize is the server name. e.g. IF one server is called Fred and another is called Bill, then instead of manually changing the URL between http://Fred.company.com/ReportServer/.... and http://Bill.company.com/ReportServer/.... the report would automatically pick up the required servername and insert it in the URL (as shown in my OP). Thanks.

Comment: Example again, with space insert to stop the hyperlink!          e.g. IF one server is called Fred and another is called Bill, then instead of manually changing the URL between "http: //Fred.company.com/ReportServer/...." and "http: //Bill.company.com/ReportServer/...." the report would automatically pick up the required servername and insert it in the URL (as shown in my OP).

Comment: Please note, that in Preview the Globals!ReportServerUrl is always empty, since your report is not deployed to any server yet, that's why you'r getting the error message.

Comment: Strangely enough I had just come to the same conclusion (of the effect if not the actual reason why) when I read your comment, so thanks for confirming that! Yes, if I ignore the "error" it still works....just not in Preview. I might see if I can fool it with an iif statement later, but next I'll try the report variable you mention below.

Comment: The expression I mentioned below already does the trik, so you can just use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following:

Instead of using the parameter, create a report variable (Report Properties... -> Variables) with the following expression:

`=Iif(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Globals!ReportServerUrl), "default_server_name", Replace(Globals!ReportServerUrl, "http://", "")).Split("/").GetValue(0)`

Replace default_server_name with your development server hostname so that it works correctly in the Preview mode.

Hope it helps.

Regards,

Alexey